# Xenial Xerus 'origami animal' instructions?

Tags: 16.04, canonical

Seemingly now almost every release has origami instructions released with it by Canonical showing you how to make the animal in the logo out of paper (clearly), so where can I find the origami instructions for Xenial Xerus (16.04)?

Also is there a place where the release of these instructions for each release is announced or an easy way of finding them? Are they listed somewhere?

Comment: I was sure I saw one, but yeah, I can't find anything either..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It gives me enormous pleasure to solve this question of the origami instructions for Xenial Xerus! The instructions have now been [posted on the Canonical design site...](https://design.canonical.com/wp-content/uploads/0d5f/Xerus-squirrel-origami.zip)

No to just get those folds just right, there are 77 steps on 4 pages and my hands are designed for a computer keyboard not folding intricate patterns into paper :)

**References:**

- [Wallpaper design for Xenial Xerus 16.04](https://design.canonical.com/2016/04/wallpaper-design-for-xenial-xerus-16-04/)

Comment: The zip attachment of the post has now disappeared, and I cannot find it via web archive or google, unfortunately

Comment: I have failed as well to find it :(

Answer (score 4):

This page suggests that the folds in the wallpaper for 16.04 are the ones you need to make to create an origami xenial xeru

http://design.canonical.com/2016/04/wallpaper-design-for-xenial-xerus-16-04/

Comment: There is no need for this answer any more.